# Hibernate auto generate table in springboot ? "Error executing DDL"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have 2 table which included foreign key to another. When i start server, my dtb have generate duplicate Column from SoTang -> so_tang,.... have null value

Example:

From:

| MaPhong |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 3 |

To:

| MaPhong | ma_phong |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

My properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quanly
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

My dtb:

```
CREATE TABLE hokhau(
    Maphong VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    SoTang INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE nhankhau (
    MaNhanKhau INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    HoTen VARCHAR(50),
    BiDanh VARCHAR(50),
    QueQuan VARCHAR(100),
    NgaySinh VARCHAR(50),
    GioiTinh VARCHAR(10),
    TonGiao VARCHAR(20),
    SoCCCD VARCHAR(15),
    Maphong VARCHAR(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (Maphong) REFERENCES hokhau(Maphong)
);
```

After I defined 2 entity, and start server, I got error "Error executing DDL"
And here is the error:

```
2024-01-10T13:01:04.725+07:00  WARN 10032 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table hokhau 
       modify column maphong  varchar(255) not null" via JDBC [Cannot change column 'Maphong': used in a foreign key constraint 'nhankhau_ibfk_1' of table 'quanly.nhankhau']

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table hokhau 
       modify column maphong  varchar(255) not null" via JDBC [Cannot change column 'Maphong': used in a foreign key constraint 'nhankhau_ibfk_1' of table 'quanly.nhankhau']
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.3.Final.jar:6.2.3.Final]
```

Answer (score 0):

try enabling the logging of SQL statements and also  ensures that Hibernate generates SQL statements compatible with MySQL

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```